# How to save and update phone number

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Can somebody help me ,How to save device phone number and how to updated it to persistent

Answer (score 1):

`Phone.getDevicePhoneNumber(true)` is supposed to return back the phone number but it doesnt work correctly.

The best way could be to ask the user for the phone number.